# CC-CE multistage amplifier

Tags: amplifier, common-emitter, common-collector

I've an unsolved exercise to ask.
The circuit is shown below:
[image]
The first question ask to find a value of R2 for which  Vout = 0 with Vin = 0.

I think this question is referred to the small signal model of the amplifier. So I've writed down the small signal model.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsWuI1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Since the Re is shorted by Ce, I find a short circuit between the emitter of T2 and the collector of T1.
It looks like (to me) that Vout doesn't depend on R2.
Where is my mistake?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ce is open at DC!!!  in my head I calc. R2~15k

Comment: *It looks like (to me) that Vout doesn't depend on R2* In large signal when Vin = 0 and R2 = 0 ohm or R2 = infinite ohms makes a **huge** difference. Same for small signal, R2 / R1 is a voltage divider so how can Vout not depend on R2 ? That question: "find a value of R2 for which Vout = 0 with Vin = 0" is unclear to me. Vout = 0 does not make much sense to me.

Comment: Ok. I really don't understand if the question I've to answer is for AC or DC.
I agree that it s wrong saying that R2 doesn't count in AC gain.
And of course it counts in DC.

@ Tony: How did you arrive at that result? Could you explain?

Comment: Simply assume Vin = 0V and notice that this circuit is supply from a split power supply +/-15V. So the question as you to find a R2 resistor value if Vin = 0V and DC voltage at T2 collector is 0V. So small-signal model is not needed.

Comment: OK. Understood.
Thanks a lot for your time, even if it was a dumb question!

Comment: Yes - I am sure that the question concerns the DC operating point only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is bias question, you need to use a large signal model.  Since it is a hand calculation, use a very simple large signal model.  Let use a voltage source of 0.7V from VB to VE and a current source of from C to E that is Beta time IB.  I'm actually going to do something simpler and assume IC = IE.  since Vo is 0, IC =15/150=100mA.  I'm going to say IE is also 100mA but you can use 101 if you want to include the base current.  I think it is to small to matter here.  So VE2=0.1*100-15=-5V. Now add each transistors 0.7v VBE to get VB1= -3.6V.  Now IR1=(15+3.6)/18000=0.001A approximately.  Since very little of this will go into the base R2=(-3.6+15)/.001=11,400 Ohms.